# Using pthread on implementation of a function which is part of an object (that is passed as parameter)

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads

We're currently trying to do some multithreaded work using pthreads

We have a class that looks like this.

```
class TestObj{
public:
void runThreaded1(int x, int y);
}
```

The class holds two functions which we need to run in a multithreaded environment, i.e have multiple threads running "runThreaded1".

We have another class which looks something like this:

```
class RunThreaded{
public:
RunThreaded(ThreadObj& object);
void run(int x, int y);
}
```

We would like to have multiple instances of the RunThreaded class. Each instance would have its own pthread that runs the implementation inside the ThreadObject that is passed on to it.

So essentially a run will look like this:

(let's say we have an instance of ThreadObj named obj in hand)

```
RunThreaded t1 = new RunThreaded(obj);
RunThreaded t2 = new RunThreaded(obj);

t1.run(4, 5);
t2.run(6, 7);

t1.run(8, 9);
t2.run(10, 11);
```

So in the example above we have two objects that each run the same implementation of runThreaded1 but on two different pthreads

Two questions:

1) What is the best way to create and use the pthread with our constraints? (i.e running a thread on an implementation of a function that is a member of some object). We found this question after some googling: 
[pthread function from a class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1151582/pthread-function-from-a-class/1151638#1151638)
and wonder if those are the only solutions for doing it. We started implementing it but ran into some issues

2) Is it possible to create the pthread once and then call the run method every time without using pthread_create? We know that pthread_create creates and runs the thread. We want to create the thread only once but be able to "run" the threaded procedure multiple times but don't know if such a pthread_run function exists

Thank you very much!

Comment: If you understand how to code a basic thread pool, how to do what you want will follow. So learn about thread pools. Or study [this code](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29742586/721269) and it should become obvious.

Comment: If you can use C++11 you can use variadic templates and make it run from any arbritrary function.