# What is the correct way of constructing multiple threads to get best performance?

Tags: c++, multithreading, performance, c++11

I want to know when using a lambda expression to define the thread, will it help to improve some performance gain. In my case, I have to run several threads. This is for real-time based application. Hence, if someone suggests to me what would be the optimal way of creating several threads. Creating threads happens in each iteration in the actual codebase. This is an example of what is happening in one iteration in high-level. Thus, this is a kind of expensive operation which is to be optimized.

```
  #include <iostream>
  #include <thread>
  #include <vector>
  #include <algorithm>

  class Task
  {
    public:
    void execute(std::string command)
    {
      //TODO actual logic
      for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
      {
        std::cout<<command<<std::endl;
      }
    }
  };

  int main()
  {          
      Task* taskPtr = new Task();
      std::vector<std::thread> workers_older;
      for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
          workers_older.push_back(std::thread(&Task::execute, taskPtr, "Task: without lambda expression"+ std::to_string(i)));
      }
      std::for_each(workers_older.begin(), workers_older.end(), [](std::thread &t) 
      {
          t.join();
      });

      std::vector<std::thread> workers;
      for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
          workers.push_back(std::thread([&]() 
          {
              taskPtr->execute("Task: "+ std::to_string(i));
          }));
      }
      std::for_each(workers.begin(), workers.end(), [](std::thread &t) 
      {
          t.join();
      });
      return 0;
  }
```

**EDIT:**
After the valuable comments about what is to be done, I have provided as an answer as they suggested

Comment: I'd be very surprised if lambda made a difference. But I encourage you to measure it. One solution is to have a pool of workers instead of spawning a thread each time. However the performance gain (or loss) totally depends on what you are really doing. Cause obviously in the code you've shown us you will loose performance with a pool (since you only have 4 tasks to process).

Comment: Hard to give you a definite answer, platform would affect the results, I would suggest you to try the different solutions in a profiler. That being said, I would assume that starting a thread, context switching and other thread stuff would completely outweigh the difference of using a lambda or sending the arguments directly to the `std::thread` constructor.

Comment: Creating threads happens in each iteration? Where are those iterations?

Comment: As you are concerned about the cost of thread creation (and you are right to do so!), you might want to reuse threads. Maybe you are looking for something like a threadpool https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26516683/reusing-thread-in-loop-c.

Comment: OT: Why not simply `for (auto& t : workers) t.join();`? Also, `return 0;` is superfluous in `main`.

Comment: This question is akin to asking "How do I pick the best strands of wool to make a coat?"      The answer is, "it depends on what you want".    There is no general-purpose answer that is applicable to every possible problem.

Comment: Every comment makes sense, thank you so much

Comment: Creating threads is the expensive part, not specifying the function to run inside the thread. Just stop creating short-lived threads and use a thread pool (or std::async/future)

Comment: Not really enough detail in the use case. A common way to get more performance out of threads is to create them on startup, possibly one per logical core, and then have an efficient way to keep those existing threads supplied with work over a longer period of time.

Answer (score 3):

There will be very little difference in overhead between passing the address of a member function and a set of parameters to the `std::thread` constructor vs passing a lambda function with appropriate captures.

The big overhead in the `std::thread` constructor is actually starting the thread itself.

If you know that you are going to want the same number of worker threads at multiple places in your program, it might be worth keeping them around as long-running threads with a queue of tasks.

Comment: Yeap, I know the number of threads to be created in each iteration. Thus,  I am going to use a thread pool.

Answer (score 1):

The biggest overhead when working with threads comes from starting a thread, scheduling,  context switching and cache utilization. The overhead of an additional indirection of a function pointer would be negligible compared to that.

Here are some points to keep in mind for optimal performance:

- Keep a pool of N threads, where N = [`std::thread::hardware_concurrency()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/hardware_concurrency) (the number of logical processors in the system)
- Submit N-1 jobs to the pool, and run the Nth job in the calling thread. The savings from not submitting the Nth job to the pool can be significant
- Avoid false sharing. Data written by different threads should be in different cache lines
- More active threads often means a larger working set. So D-cache utilization may decrease, impacting performance

Here's my working example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

struct thread_pool {
    thread_pool(int threads = std::thread::hardware_concurrency()) : size(threads) {
        grp.reserve(threads);
        for (int i = 0; i < threads; ++i)
            grp.emplace_back([this] { return service.run(); });
    }

    template<typename F, typename ...Args>
    auto enqueue(F& f, Args... args) -> std::future<decltype(f(args...))> {
        return boost::asio::post(service,
            std::packaged_task<decltype(f(args...))()>([&f, args...]{ return f(args...); })
        );
    }

    ~thread_pool() {
        service_work.reset();
        for (auto &t : grp)
            if (t.joinable())
                t.join();
        service.stop();
    }

    const int size;
private:
    boost::asio::io_service service;
    std::unique_ptr<boost::asio::io_service::work> service_work {new boost::asio::io_service::work(service)};
    std::vector<std::thread> grp;
};

int main() {
    thread_pool pool;
    std::vector<std::future<int>> results;
    auto task = [](int i) { return i + 1; };
    for (int i = 0; i < pool.size - 1; i++) {
        results.emplace_back(pool.enqueue(task, i));
    }
    int sum = task(pool.size - 1); // last task run synchronously
    for (auto& res : results) {
        sum += res.get();
    }
    std::cout << sum << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your valuable thoughts, but I guess this code only works for c+14 onwards? But, the answer which I provided works for c++11 as well.

Comment: @GPrathap it's only the make_unique that is C++14. I updated the q. so it should work for C++11 now.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much for everybody all the very valuable thoughts. I have decided to use a thread pool for the task. I am sorry, regarding not explained whole logic which is quite long and I thought it was not required.

Here is my proposed solution. I got initial code from [here](https://gist.github.com/wush978/6190443) and modified as the way I wanted.

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <unistd.h>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <thread>
    #include <vector>
    #include <algorithm>
    #include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
    #include <boost/make_shared.hpp>

    #include <boost/thread.hpp>
    #include <boost/bind.hpp>
    #include <boost/asio.hpp>
    #include <boost/move/move.hpp>
    #include <boost/make_unique.hpp>

    namespace asio = boost::asio; 

    typedef boost::packaged_task<int> task_t;
    typedef boost::shared_ptr<task_t> ptask_t;

    class Task
    {
    public:
    int execute(std::string command)
    {
      //TODO actual logic
      std::cout<< "\nThread:" << command << std::endl;
      int sum = 0;
      for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
      {
        sum+=i;
      }
      return sum;
    }
  };


    void push_job(Task* worker, std::string seconds, boost::asio::io_service& io_service
                , std::vector<boost::shared_future<int> >& pending_data) {
      ptask_t task = boost::make_shared<task_t>(boost::bind(&Task::execute, worker, seconds));
      boost::shared_future<int> fut(task->get_future());
      pending_data.push_back(fut);
      io_service.post(boost::bind(&task_t::operator(), task));
    }

    int main()
    {
        Task* taskPtr = new Task();

        boost::asio::io_service io_service;
        boost::thread_group threads;
        std::unique_ptr<boost::asio::io_service::work> service_work;
        service_work = boost::make_unique<boost::asio::io_service::work>(io_service);
        for (int i = 0; i < boost::thread::hardware_concurrency() ; ++i)
        {
          threads.create_thread(boost::bind(&boost::asio::io_service::run,
            &io_service));
        }
        std::vector<boost::shared_future<int> > pending_data; // vector of futures

        push_job(taskPtr, "4", io_service, pending_data);
        push_job(taskPtr, "5", io_service, pending_data);
        push_job(taskPtr, "6", io_service, pending_data);
        push_job(taskPtr, "7", io_service, pending_data);

        boost::wait_for_all(pending_data.begin(), pending_data.end());
        int total_sum = 0;
        for(auto result : pending_data){
           total_sum += result.get();
        }
        std::cout<< "Total sum: "<< total_sum << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }
```