# Semaphore implementation - should notify() release the mutex before notifying the condition_variable?

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, c++17

I've seen a lot of implementations of the semaphore where the `notify()` function looks something like this:
(this particular example is from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4792449/c0x-has-no-semaphores-how-to-synchronize-threads))

```
void notify() {
        std::lock_guard<decltype(mutex_)> lock(mutex_);
        ++count_;
        condition_.notify_one();
    }
```

I don't understand the reason behind holding the lock while calling `notify_one()`. Even if a spurious wake-up occurs after releasing the mutex but before notifying the condition variable, everything should work fine (since `condition_.wait()` should use a predicate to handle spurious wakeups anyway).

Are there any cases where this:

```
void notify() {
        {
        std::scoped_lock lock(mutex_);
        ++count_;
        }
        condition_.notify_one();
    }
```

would fail?

Comment: Some condition variables do require the lock be held for the notify for [various reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46234855/8586227); it might just be habit that people do so where it’s explicitly not required.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48958530/should-condition-variable-notify-all-be-covered-by-mutex-lock this is an almost identical question that I asked.  It has good answers that will help with your understanding of this subject.

Answer (score 2):

According to [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable) (emphasis mine):

> The thread that intends to modify the variable has to
>
> 1. acquire a std::mutex (typically via std::lock_guard)
> 2. perform the modification while the lock is held
> 3. execute notify_one or notify_all on the std::condition_variable **(the lock does not need to be held for notification)**

So either of the code sequences in your post should be OK.