# waiting on worker thread using std::atomic flag and std::condition_variable

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++17

Here is a C++17 snippet where one thread waits for another to reach certain stage:

```
std::condition_variable  cv;
std::atomic<bool>        ready_flag{false};
std::mutex               m;


// thread 1
... // start a thread, then wait for it to reach certain stage
auto lock = std::unique_lock(m);
cv.wait(lock, [&]{ return ready_flag.load(std::memory_order_acquire); });


// thread 2
... // modify state, etc
ready_flag.store(true, std::memory_order_release);
std::lock_guard{m};   // NOTE: this is lock immediately followed by unlock
cv.notify_all();
```

As I understand this is a valid way to use atomic flag and condition variable to achieve the goal. For example there is no need to use `std::memory_order_seq_cst` here.

Is it possible to relax this code even further? For example:

- maybe using `std::memory_order_relaxed` in `ready_flag.load()`
- maybe using `std::atomic_thread_fence()` instead of `std::lock_guard{m};`

Comment: I think as such you don't need std::atomic at all because you are inside the lock. However you need to set the flag inside the lock

Comment: Did you measure your performance and found a bottleneck?

Comment: @bertubezz, I need flag to be atomic for some reasons unrelated to this question.

Comment: @jtbandes, aim is to relax logic as much as possible while staying within constraints of C++ memory model. Performance is irrelevant

Comment: @bertubezz In thread 2, the `ready_flag` is set to `true` outside the lock.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz So? It's set before the unlock.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly: this code is indeed valid. The `lock_guard` prior to the `notify_one` call ensures that the waiting thread will see the correct value of `ready_flag` when it wakes, whether that is due to a spurious wake, or due to the call to `notify_one`.

Secondly: if the only accesses to the `ready_flag` are those shown here, then the use of `atomic` is overkill. Move the write to `ready_flag` inside the scope of the `lock_guard` on the writer thread and use a simpler, more conventional pattern.

If you stick with this pattern, then whether or not you can use `memory_order_relaxed` depends on the ordering semantics you require.

If the thread that sets the `ready_flag` also writes to other objects which will be read by the reader thread, then you *need* the acquire/release semantics in order to ensure that the data is correctly visible: the reader thread may lock the mutex and see the new value of `ready_flag` *before* the writer thread has locked the mutex, in which case the mutex itself would provide no ordering guarantees.

If there is no other data touched by the thread that sets the `ready_flag`, or that data is protected by another mutex or other synchronization mechanism, then you can use `memory_order_relaxed` everywhere, as it is only the value of `ready_flag` itself that you care about, and not the ordering of any other writes.

`atomic_thread_fence` doesn't help with this code under any circumstances. If you are using a condition variable, then the `lock_guard{m}` is required.

Comment: Code is simplified, in real life `ready_flag` is more complicated structure (like non-blocking single linked list) that gets populated in complicated logic and I do not want to wake up other threads at the moment it gets populated yet (in fact I only want to wake them up if previously list was empty). Code is tolerant to spurious wake ups, if processing thread grabs element prematurely -- it is fine and taken care of. In fact, slist can be populated by other threads (doesnt happen in my case)

Comment: Anyway, my point is that setting "flag" and waking other(s) are two actions that can have significant distance between them (or I don't want to get blocked by mutex at point when flag is set, or I want other threads to be able to check flag without locking, etc). Wrt relaxing, I have a good feeling about using fully relaxed load in `cv.wait()`, but not 100% sure about that...

Answer (score 1):

The combined use of a `std:atomic` and `std:condition_variable` is unconventional and should be avoided,
but it can be interesting to analyse the behavior if you come across this in a code review and need to decide if a patch is required.

I believe there are 2 problems:

1. Since `ready_flag` is not protected by the `std:mutex`, you cannot rely on the guarantee that thread 1 will observe the updated value once `wait` wakes up from `notify_one`.
   If the store to `ready_flag` in thread 2 is delayed by the platform, thread 1 may see the old value (`false`) and enter `wait` again (possibly causing a deadlock).
   Whether a delayed store is possible depends on your platform. On a strongly ordered platform such as `X86`, you are probably safe, but again, no guarantees from the C++ standard.
   Also note that using a stronger memory ordering does not help here.
2. let's say, the store is not delayed and once `wait` wakes up, `ready_flag` loads `true`.
   This time, based on the memory ordering you are using, the store to `ready_flag` in thread 2, synchronizes with the load in thread 1 which can now safely access the modified state written by thread 2.

   But, this only works one time. You cannot reset `ready_flag` and write to the shared state again. That would introduce a data race since the shared state can now be accessed unsynchronized by both threads

> Is it possible to relax this code even further

Because you are modifying the shared state outside the lock, release/acquire ordering on `ready_flag` is necessary for synchronization.

To make this a portable solution, access both the shared state and `ready_flag` while protected by the mutex (`ready_flag` can be a plain `bool`).
This is how the mechanism is designed to be used.

```
std::condition_variable  cv;
bool                     ready_flag{false}; // not atomic
std::mutex               m;


// thread 1
... // start a thread, then wait for it to reach certain stage
auto lock = std::unique_lock(m);
cv.wait(lock, [&] { return ready_flag; });
ready_flag = false;
// access shared state


// thread 2
auto lock = std::unique_lock(m);
... // modify state, etc
ready_flag = true;
lock.unlock();  // optimization
cv.notify_one();
```

Unlocking the mutex before the call to `notify_one` is an optimization. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17101922/do-i-have-to-acquire-lock-before-calling-condition-variable-notify-one) for more details.

Comment: The code in the question is portable, valid code, provided there are no other writes to `ready_flag`.

Comment: @LWimsey -- I don't think you are correct wrt point #1. mutex lock+unlock prevents deadlock you mentioned about. Wrt further relaxing -- I am almost positive `load()` in  `cv.wait()` can be fully relaxed, but not 100% :) -- hence this post.

Comment: @C.M. I cannot find anything in the standard that convinces me the store in T2 cannot be delayed. Or, to put it this way, if it deadlocks (per #1 in my answer), what part of the standard is violated ?

Comment: @C.M. & AnthonyWilliams, I think I found the quote in the standard I was looking for. N4713, 33.5.4 says: _The implementation shall behave as if all executions of notify_one, notify_all, and each part of the wait, wait_for, and wait_until executions are executed in a single unspecified total order consistent with the "happens before" order._. It looks like it cannot deadlock then.