# C++11 condition variable semantics

Tags: c++, c++11, concurrency, semantics, condition-variable

I am trying to understand the semantics of [std::condition_variable](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable). I thought I had a decent understanding of the C++11 concurrency model (atomics, memory ordering, the corresponding [guarantees and formal relations](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/memory_order)), but the description on how to use condition variables correctly seems to contradict my understanding.

### TL;DR

The [reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable) says:

> The thread that intends to modify the variable has to
>
> 1. acquire a std::mutex (typically via std::lock_guard)
> 2. perform the modification while the lock is held
> 3. execute notify_one or notify_all on the std::condition_variable (the lock does not need to be held for notification)
>
> Even if the shared variable is atomic, it must be modified under the mutex in order to correctly publish the modification to the waiting thread.

I can see why the modification may have to be done *before releasing* the mutex, but the above seems to be fairly clear that it has to be *whilst holding* the mutex, i.e. it cannot be *before acquiring* it. Am I reading this correctly?

### In more detail

If my reading of the above is correct, then why is this so? Consider we do the modification(s) before the critical section (ensuring no race conditions, via correct use of atomics and locks). E.g.

```
std::atomic<bool> dummy;
std::mutex mtx;
std::condition_variable cv;

void thread1() {
    //...
    // Modify some program data, possibly in many places, over a long period of time
    dummy.store(true, std::memory_order_relaxed); // for simplicity
    //...
    mtx.lock(); mtx.unlock();
    cv.notify_one();
    //...
}

void thread2() {
    // ...
    { std::unique_lock<std::mutex> ul(mtx);
        cv.wait(ul, []() -> bool {
            // A complex condition, possibly involving data from many places
            return dummy.load(std::memory_order_relaxed); // for simplicity
        });
    }
    // ...
}
```

My understanding is that `cv.wait()` locks on `mtx` before proceeding (to check the condition and execute the rest of the program). Furthermore, `std::mutex::lock()` counts as an *acquire* operation and `std::mutex::unlock()` counts as a *release* operation. Would this not imply that the unlock() in thread1 *synchronizes-with* the lock() in thread2, and hence all atomic and even non-atomic stores performed in thread1 before `unlock()` are visible to thread2 when it wakes up?

```
Formally:  store --sequenced-before--> unlock() --synchronizes-with--> lock() --sequenced-before--> load
...and so: store --happens-before--> load
```

Thanks a lot for any answers!

[Note: I find it weird that I haven't found an answer to this after extensive googling; I'm sorry if it is a duplicate...]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the time before locking the mutex in thread1 and the time before the condition_variable first unlocks the mutex in thread2.

thread1 does

- Modify a lot of program data
- `dummy.store(true, std::memory_order_relaxed)`

thread2 does

- Lock the mutex
- `dummy.load(std::memory_order_relaxed)` (to check the predicate before waiting)

There is no sequencing with respect to each other. If thread2 sees a true value for `dummy` at this check, and continues on, there is no guarantee that any of the data modifications are visible to thread2. thread2 will continue on, having correctly seen the value of `dummy` but without correctly seeing the modifications.

You say "ensuring no race conditions, via correct use of atomics and locks" which is very open. Relaxed atomics would be correct and modifications would not necessarily be visible in thread2. However, hypothetical additional synchronization around those other data modifications could guarantee visibility.

In other words, there should be some release-acquire ordering, between the store and the load.

This is similar to: [waiting on worker thread using std::atomic flag and std::condition_variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59165685/waiting-on-worker-thread-using-stdatomic-flag-and-stdcondition-variable)

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot. The link answered my question. (Just for reference to anyone reading this:) I think you've missed the fact that the mutex is locked and unlocked, which already functions as a release-acquire pair (as explained in the first answer under the link), so I'm now convinced the code above is correct.

Comment: @EMarci15 I don't think you're making a right conclusion in the comment above.

Comment: @EMarci15 the difference between your question and the linked one is `memory_order_relaxed` vs `memory_order_release` on the write to the atomic flag.

Comment: @ciamej Ok, I see what you mean. Yes, I could have been more clear: in my case, every other guarantee I need for correctness is taken care of by atomics and memory ordering, the only guarantee I need here is no lost signals (that is, if thread1 sets `dummy` to `true` and notifies thread2, then T2 should wake up and see `dummy==true`)

Comment: I think the only guarantee given is "if T2 wakes up due to T1 signalling (not spuriously or just by reaching the `wait()` call before any signals), then it will always see all modifications made by T1 before the `notify_one()` call (more specifically, the `mtx.unlock()` call right before that)". That is correct, right?

Comment: @EMarci15 it's hard to comment without `every other guarantee I need for correctness is taken care of` being shown explicitly ;) with just the `memory_order_relaxed` store to `dummy` I don't think there is such a guarantee as you describe. Assume that before dummy you store a value to some other atomic variable possibly with `memory_order_release`, even if thread two wakes and observes `dummy == true`, there is no guarantee it will observe the store to the other atomic variable. Note that, T2 can observe `dummy == true` even if T1 did not reach the lock/unlock/signal part of its code.

Comment: I fully understand that, that is not what I said

Comment: there's an "if" part to the guarantee I described

Comment: @EMarci15 maybe you could provide an example condition that is evaluated in T2 and some example code that precedes dummy store in T1, and then it would be easier to discuss.

Comment: @EMarci15 ok, that's fair. But, consider that using condition variables that way is very 'un-idiomatic' to say the least. There's a reason why programmers are advised to check the condition in a loop and so on. Making condition variables work as expected is a tricky stuff. Just from a code review standpoint I would suggest designing synchronization in such a way that the desired effects you with to achieve in T2 are based on some state invariant that is independent of whether T1 managed to signal T2 or not.

Comment: @ciamej Ok, thanks. I think I'm happy with my understanding now once again. :D (Just as a side-note, wait() with a predicate 2nd argument already performs the loop. ;))

Comment: I think it was just a case of too much oversimplification for the question for the sake of theoretical understanding, rather than bad design in my actual code :)