# condition_variable: notifying after releasing lock optimization effect

Tags: c++, qt, winapi, boost, condition-variable

It was already asked few times about whether one should notify `condition_variable` while holding a lock:

```
        lk.lock();
        // change state
        cv.notify_one();
        lk.unlock();
```

or after releasing it:

```
        lk.lock();
        // change state
        lk.unlock();
        cv.notify_one();
```

Here's one of such questions: [Do I have to acquire lock before calling condition_variable.notify_one()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17101922/do-i-have-to-acquire-lock-before-calling-condition-variable-notify-one/)

Answers point out that both are safe, as long as the lock is held at all when condition is changed, and **the later form is better for performance**: awaken thread is immediately unlocked.

**I'm wondering how much this performance effect is generic and significant**:

- Does this apply to Windows `CONDITION_VARIABLE` (that is avaliable since Vista+, but I'm nostly asking about Windows 10 implementation)? If so, how much significant the effect is?
- Does this apply to Qt `QWaitCondition` on Windows?
- Does this apply to `boost::condition_variable` on Windows?
- Does it apply to most Linux systems where POSIX condition variable is the underlying implementation? Is there a measure of it?

The practical application is that I have to use the first form, where notification is done under the lock, as a structure that manages condition variables needs protection as well, so I want to know how much this approach worth avoiding.

Comment: The answer will depend more on the implementation of the various mutexes than the condition variable. In scenario one you're effectively racing the notifying thread's call to `unlock` with the notified thread that is trying to acquire the mutex.

Comment: I'd write 2x3 test cases simulating some typical behavior in your codebase to measure the performance. I believe that'll give more value than theoretical answers here.

Comment: Just measure. It's gonna keep on being locking, so don't expect any big gains. Also, I think the key difference is not perf of "a single wakeup" but rather emergent behaviour - specifically _fair scheduling_. If you play it loose, the guarantees no thread will starve cannot be made.